# Resize Element Height Depending on Image Inside

Tags: css, image, height

I'm trying to find out how to define the height for this `.gallery` element based on the size of the `img` element inside it.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="large-10 columns">
            <div class="gallery portrait">
                <div class="cover">
                    <img src="http://placekitten.com/800/1029">
                </div>
                <ul class="thumbs">
                    <li class="thumb"></li>
                    <li class="thumb"></li>
                    <li class="thumb"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm using percentage-based heights and widths in my CSS to set the height and width of the elements inside my gallery. However, I'm defining the height of the `.gallery` element in pixels so my percentage elements work.

```
.gallery {
  height: 680px;
}
```

I'm trying to get the height of the `.gallery` to adjust its self when the browser window is resized and my image gets smaller.

I've got a demo of the problem I'm having over here: http://codepen.io/realph/pen/kKAmx

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what your issue correctly, then simply remove the `height:` entries on your gallery and cover class. The `gallery` element should expand contract to fit the image (as long as the image has % width).

**[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2XF95/)**

CSS:

```
.gallery {
 background: orange;
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 //height: 680px;
}

.cover {
  float: right;
  width: 63.8554217%; 
  //height: 680px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery img {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: The problem I'm having is once I remove height from my `.gallery` class the rest of the elements have no height to assume their percentages? For example the `.thumbs` element has a height of 33%. Without its container (`.gallery`) having a fixed height, that 33% means nothing.